# C# Selenium Finding an element by a parameter of onclick() attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Okay I've got a set of elements that do not have consistent IDs but they do have a long onclick that has a unique identifier see below.  These elements can overlap so I don't want to try a css style selector.

```
<a  href="#" onclick="fireEntrySelected('scheduleFrm',
'scheduleFrm:selectableClassType', '12345678901234567890123456789123_12');"
class="selectableClassType" style="position: absolute; height: 42px; 
top: 88px; left: 5%; width: 2%; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; 
border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(255, 235, 205);
background-color: rgb(255, 235, 205); display: inline-block;"
id="__autoIdNumXwhereXchangingOnReloads">
<span class="title" style="line-height: 15px;">
Title information that can be repeated on the page</span>
</a>
```

I need to cycle through every one of these appointments so what I'd like to do 
is click it with something like:

```
 driver2.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[contains(onclick,'12345678901234567890123456789123_12')]")).click()
```

Which fails with no such element and I've verified the number shows up on there on the page and only one time.  I'm using `ChromeDriver` in `selenium` on `c#`, so:

1. What selector will get this element?
2. What's wrong with my selector?
3. Does anyone have a good resource for the `C#` selenium webdriver `XPath` selector I'm probably missing something obvious ,but I have not found good documentation.

on the plus side I realized I can just do the java call, so I have a hackish answer, but not a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `@` before the attribute name:

```
//*[contains(@onclick, '12345678901234567890123456789123_12')]
         HERE^
```

I don't think this is, generally speaking, a reliable locator, but to provide a better option, we should see the complete HTML of the page and know what information you have and can use to locate the element.

Answer (score 1):

> What selector will get this element?

As you've mentioned they do have a long onclick that has a unique identifier, So the best locator would be `cssSelector` to locate this element as below :-

```
 driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("a[onclick *= '12345678901234567890123456789123_12']")).Click();
```

> What's wrong with my selector?

You `xpath` logically incorrect, you're missing to append `@` before element attribute name, it should be as below :-

```
driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@onclick,'12345678901234567890123456789123_12')]")).Click();
```

> Does anyone have a good resource for the C# selenium webdriver XPath selector I'm probably missing something obvious ,but I have not found good documentation

- [Xpath Syntax Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [Xpath Axes Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xpath_axes.asp)
- [Css Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much the resources are worth even more than the first anwser.